# my Lagrange Interpolation algorithm doesn't work well

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

```
import numpy as np
def lagr(P) :

    A = list()
    for i in range(0, len(P)) :
        A.append(P[i][0])

    B = list()
    for i in range(0, len(P)) :
        B.append(P[i][1])

    F = []
    for i in range(0, len(A)) :
        AA = list()
        for k in range(0, len(P)) :
            AA.append(A[k])

        del AA[i]

        ff = np.poly1d(AA, True)

        aa = 1
        for j in range(0, len(AA)) :
            aa  *= A[i] - AA[j]

        f = ff * B[i] / aa
        F.append(f)

    addf = 0
    for k in F :
        addf = addf + k

    return addf
```

Example

```
P = [[0, 1], [1, 4], [3, 2]]
lagr(P)
>>>poly1d([-1.33333333,  4.33333333,  1.        ])
```

This is my code... I researched many materials explaining Lagrange interpolation. Based on them, I created an algorithm for myself.
I almost succssed this. For three points(resulting in quadratic function), I found my algorithm work well. I examined this in geogebra.
But... my goal is making an 59th degree function, with 60 points. This is my task, so I put these 60 points to my algorithm, but the result is terrible....

I put list H(that has ordered pair elements) and I examined this resulting function really pass these points. I used `np.polyval` function and I put 1 to it. But the result is not what I expected...

My task

```
A = [27, 35.1, 26.3, 32.5, 29.1, 32.9, 28.4, 33.5, 26.4, 32.1, 26, 31.4, 25.7, 30.9, 24, 27.8, 25,         27.6, 24.8, 30.5, 23.9, 29.6,
     27.3, 31.8, 26.1, 30.4, 25.7, 29.5, 26.4, 33, 26.4, 34, 26.9, 32.1, 28, 34.9, 26.5, 34.1, 27,     32.7, 27.2, 31.1, 27.6, 33.8,
 27.9, 34.8, 28.4, 34.2, 27.6, 33.3, 28, 32.8, 28.6, 33.1, 27.9, 32.5, 26.3, 29, 25.9, 31]

B = list(range(1, 61))

x = len(A)
H = []
for i in range(0, x) :
    h = [B[i], A[i]]
    H.append(h)

print(H)
f = lagr(H)
np.polyval(f, 1)
>>>-20992.0
```

I put list H(that has ordered pair elements) and I examined this resulting function really pass these points. I used `np.polyval` function and I put 1 to it. But the result is not what I expected(My expected result was 27)...

Comment: There is no way to get a 59th degree interpolation to do even remotely the right thing, given compound IEEE floating point errors. Even a 15th order is almost certainly going to do the wrong thing. This is why we generally use piecewise low order curves instead: you don't draw one giant curve, you draw lots of reasonably well behaved curves with C1, G2, or C2 continuity.